# sudo npm fails, env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, npm, homebrew

After uninstalling and reinstalling node and npm I can no longer run npm as sudo. This is on a Mac. I have tried the official node installer and brew.

It works from my user but any attempt to run sudo npm produces this error:

```
 $ sudo npm
 env: node: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

`npm` most likely is installed at `/usr/local`, but `/usr/local` is not on the `$PATH` of the root user. You can configure `sudo` to allow the `$PATH` to be changed, but if you installed `npm` with Homebrew you shouldn't have to use `sudo` at all.

Comment: @Shajo: Not using `sudo` when installing things with `npm`.

Comment: The following command also throws the same error  npm install less

Comment: @Shajo: It sounds like perhaps `npm` was installed via `sudo`.